# Move through a dictionary in a JavaScript recursive function

Tags: javascript

I have a dictionary that has certain callback functions. For example:

```
const CallBacks = {'a': CallBackA, 'b': CallBackB, 'c': CallBackC };
```

I need to write a function that looks like this.

```
function CallAllCallBacks(CallBackValue,CallBackFunc){
    var Res = CallBackFunc(CallBackValue);
    CallAllCallBacks(NextKeyInDictionary, NextValueInDictionary);
}
CallAllCallBacks('a',CallBacks['a']);
```

Where `CallBackA, CallBackB, CallBackC` are all some functions.

How to move through the dictionary while executing the function recursively?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "next key"? Objects are unordered collections.

Comment: Why do it recursively instead of using a simple `for … in` loop?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that makes sense, but I just wanted a function that gives me one by one key-value pairs even if they are not in any order. A simple  for … in loop wouldn't work in my case because all call backs establish a connection to a hardware and communicate. So  for … in loop wouldn't help me work synchronously which means multiple connections and multiple commands could be sent over simultaneously. So, I needed a truly callback like structure where methods starts to execute only after previous method is completed even if there is some delay. So, recursion was the best option I thought.

Comment: Ah. You'll want to use `async`/`await` then :-) Alternatively, `Object.entries(…).values()` gives you an iterator from which you can fetch some "next" key/value pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

This will convert the callback dictionary to a multi-dimensional array.

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

> The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own
> enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs

Example:

```
Object.entries(CallBacks);

// output: 
// [ 
//   [ 'a', ƒ CallBackA() ], 
//   [ 'b', ƒ CallBackB() ], 
//   [ 'c', ƒ CallBackC() ] 
// ]
```

With this conversion you have the flexibility to do a recursive or iterative approach.

---

**Recursive approach**

```js
// callback examples
const CallBackA = (k) => console.log(k, 'CallBackA');
const CallBackB = (k) => console.log(k, 'CallBackB');
const CallBackC = (k) => console.log(k, 'CallBackC');

// callbacks
const CallBacks = {
  a: CallBackA,
  b: CallBackB,
  c: CallBackC
};

// dictionary entries
const entries = Object.entries(CallBacks);

function CallAllCallBacks(entries) {
  // base case
  if (entries.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  // remove first element and capture its [key, value] pair
  const [key, cb] = entries.shift();
  // invoke callback
  var Res = cb(key);
  // do something with Res
  // ...
  // recurse
  return CallAllCallBacks(entries);
}

// invoke recursive function
CallAllCallBacks(entries);
```

Note in the recursive solution [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) is used to:

- remove first array element from `entries`
- store the removed element in a `const`

Also note that we can destructure this removed element since it is an array containing a `[key, value]` pair - see docs on [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

---

**Iterative approach**

```js
// callback examples
const CallBackA = (k) => console.log(k, 'CallBackA');
const CallBackB = (k) => console.log(k, 'CallBackB');
const CallBackC = (k) => console.log(k, 'CallBackC');

// callbacks
const CallBacks = {
  a: CallBackA,
  b: CallBackB,
  c: CallBackC
};

function CallAllCallBacks([CallBackValue, CallBackFunc]) {
  var Res = CallBackFunc(CallBackValue);
}

Object.entries(CallBacks).forEach(CallAllCallBacks);
```

An even shorter iterative approach would be:

```js
const CallBackA = (v) => console.log(v, 'CallBackA');
const CallBackB = (v) => console.log(v, 'CallBackB');
const CallBackC = (v) => console.log(v, 'CallBackC');

const CallBacks = {
  a: CallBackA,
  b: CallBackB,
  c: CallBackC
};
for (const [key, cb] of Object.entries(CallBacks)) {
  var Res = cb(key);
}
```

---

With a small dictionary, it's perfectly fine to do either iterative or recursive.

However, if your dictionary contains thousands of entries, you should probably go with the iterative approach.

All modern browsers (besides Safari) have dropped support for [tail call optimization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PX0BV9hGZY) (TCO). Node.js does not support it either.

So using recursion with thousands of entries could produce stack overflow errors on non-Safari platforms.

---

[Big-O Notation](https://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf) assuming no support for TCO

*Iterative execution:*

- time: `O(n)`
- space: `O(1)`

*Recursive execution:*

- time: `O(n)`
- space: `O(n)`

Recursive execution is more expensive on space because each recursion adds a new frame to the call-stack i.e. `n` recursions are added to memory.